# Deleting and Contract a matroid diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am in the middle of writing my proposal which is on matroids. 
In part of the proposal I need to draw a matroid where an element is being deleted on one side and the same element is being contracted on the other. Similar to this,
[image]

my issue is that I am very brand new to tikz and I dont know how to do this. 
Can some one guide me to a instruction site that helps one draw matroids??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: The pgf-tikz manual has a few tutorial that should get you on the run to redraw the image shown. Right now, this is jusst a Do It For Me-Question and getting an answer depends on the mood of possible helpers. Welcome, by the way.

Comment: @Jo Thanks! Ill look into the tikz manual for help. I just uploaded a matroid picture for reference. This matroid is not the one I need to put in my paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good opportunity to get to grips with the graph drawing library (see the PGF manual part IV as well as chapter 19 in Part III), particularly the concept of "subgraph nodes" (see 27.10 "Using Several Different Layouts to Draw a Single Graph" in the `3.0.1a` manual).

Unfortunately, despite all the fancy layout algorithms, often when a specific layout is required, is still necessary to position nodes manually. Adjustments between layers is also a bit of a fiddle. However, it is a bit less hassle than doing it without the graph library.

Compile with `LuaLaTeX`

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees,circular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every loop/.style={}, >=Triangle]
\graph [dots/.style={
  empty nodes, 
  nodes={
    circle, fill, inner sep=0, minimum size=0.75ex
  }}, 
  binary tree layout]{
  % Root
  root/ // [simple necklace layout, dots] {
      a -- b -- c -- d -- a, b -- d;
    };
  % First layer
  child1/ // [simple necklace layout, dots] {
      a1 -- b1 -- c1 -- d1 -- a1
    };
  child2/[minimum height=1cm] // [no layout, dots] {
      a2[at=(180:1)], b2[at=(0:0)],  c2[at=(0:1)];
      a2 --[bend left] b2 -- [bend left] c2; c2 --[bend left] b2 --[bend left] a2;
    };
   % Second layer
   child11/ // [no layout, dots, /tikz/.cd, x=0.707cm, y=0.707cm] {
       a11[at=(0:1)], b11[at=(90:1)], c11[at=(180:1)], d11[at=(270:1)];
       a11 -- b11 -- c11 -- d11;
     };
   child12/ // [no layout, dots, /tikz/.cd, x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm] {
       a12[at=(90:1)], b12[at=(210:1)], c12[at=(330:1)];
       a12 -- b12 -- c12 -- a12;
     };
   child21/[minimum height=1cm] // [no layout, dots] {
       a21[at=(180:1)], b21[at=(0:0)], c21[at=(0:1)];
       a21 -- b21 --[bend left] c21 --[bend left] b21;
     };
   child22/[minimum height=1cm] // [no layout, dots] {
       a22[at=(0:0)] --[bend left] b22[at=(0:1)] --[bend left] a22 --[loop left] a22;
     };
   % Third layer
   child121/ // [no layout, dots, /tikz/.cd, x=0.707cm, y=0.707cm] {
       a121[at=(180:1)], b121[at=(90:1)], c121[at=(0:1)];
       a121 -- b121 -- c121;
     };
   child122/[minimum height=1cm] // [no layout, dots] {
     a122[at=(0:0)], b122[at=(0:1)];
     a122 --[bend left] b122 --[bend left] a122;
   };
   child211/ // [no layout, dots] {
     a211[at=(270:1)], b211[at=(0:0)], c211[at=(0:1)];
     a211 -- b211 -- c211;
   };
   child212/ // [no layout, dots] {
     a212[at=(270:1)], b212[at=(0:0)];
     a212 --[loop below] a212 -- b212;
   };
   child221/ // [no layout, dots] {
     a221[at=(270:1)], b221[at=(0:0)];
     a221 -- b221 --[loop above] b221;
   };
   child222/[minimum height=1.5cm] // [no layout, dots]{
     a222 --[loop below] a222 --[loop above] a222;
   };
   % Fourth layer
   child1221/ // [no layout, dots] {
     a1221[at=(0:0)], b1221[at=(0:1)];
     a1221 -- b1221;
   };
   child1222/ // [no layout, dots] {
     a1222 --[loop left] a1222;
   };
   % Tree of subgraph nodes
   root -> {
    child1 -> {
      child11 [label=below:$x^3$],
      child12 -> {
        child121 [label=below:$x^2$],
        child122 -> {
          child1221 [label=below:$x$],
          child1222 [label=below:$y$]
        }
      }
    },
    child2 -> {
      child21 -> {
        child211 [label=below:$x^2$],
        child212 [label={[shift=(270:0.5)]below:$xy$}]
      }, 
      child22 -> {
        child221 [label=below:$xy$],
        child222 [label=below:$y^2$]
      }
    }
  };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]